# how to catch EOL with regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I want to catch/match with regular expression in python, it's a multiline string, so it has EOL in the middle, but my regular expression doesn't work in that situation and gives the error as below, anybody knows how to handle it? Thanks!

---

```
import re
comment = re.compile(r'/((.|\n)*)/')
text="/hello!
/"
m=re.findall(comment, text)
if m:
```

### print(m)

Error I got:

File "", line 3
    text="/hello!/
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Your regex has absolutely nothing to do with this, it's your string literal `text` that is failing.  Either make it a triple-quoted string so that it's allowed to span multiple lines, or use `\n` to create the linebreak.

Comment: @jasonharper: Make your comment an answer, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`m=re.findall(comment, text, re.DOTALL)`

allows `.` to match newline (I assume thats the question)

```
print(re.findall("\/.*?\/","""/hel
lo!/""",re.DOTALL))
# ['/hel\nlo!/']

print(re.findall("\/.*?\/","""/hel
lo111/garbage
asd more garbage /h
ello222/""",re.DOTALL))
# ['/hel\nlo111/', '/h\nello222/']
```